# Ubuntu wont finish booting up in fresh install

Tags: boot, system-installation, 19.04

Seeing how today the new version of Ubuntu comes out I wanted to install it in my laptop. I installed the ISO image in a USB with Rufus, booted up the USB in my laptop without issues, and installed Ubuntu while changing the partitions I previously had (Deleted a Windows I never used, with the booting partition that Windows creates for itself, plus my / and /home partitions).

Made the new partitions (ext4 /boot at the start, swap, ext4 /home and ext4 / plus an NTFS partition that I use to store files and info, I left this partition as is) and installed without issues.

So, right when I reboot, it boots into Ubuntu fine but it hangs at the initial services startup, I'm not sure if a service is hanging or what but I always end up with a screen looking like this (see image)
[image: boot picture showing the starting services]

That "Hold until boot process finishes up" never seems to finish, or there must be a service that never starts (or finishes), so it never ends.

If I push the power button the laptop powers off, so there must be something holding this stage of the boot up.

My laptop is an MSI CX61 2PC, and never had a problem like this before.

I'm gonna have to go back to 18.04 :/